# how to store image from url to sqlite?

Tags: android, json, sqlite

sorry, i'm new in adnroid programming , i try combination JSONParse and sqlite, when i store (insert) data to sqlite my column image = null (not save in sqlite), 
how to get image from url and store(insert) to sqlite ?

this is my code main activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button Btngetdata;

    // URL to get JSON Array
    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2:81/bantulfolder/alldata.php";

    private String IMAGEURL = "http://10.0.2.2:81/bantulfolder/";

    private byte[] logoImage;

    // JSON Node Names
    private static final String TAG_DATA = "data";
    public static final String TAG_IDT = "idt";
    public static final String TAG_IDL = "idl";
    public static final String TAG_NAMA = "nama";
    public static final String TAG_ALAMAT = "alamat";
    public static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";

    JSONArray user = null;

    private DatabaseHandler databaseHelper;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);

        Btngetdata = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getdata);
        Btngetdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                new JSONParse().execute();
            }
        });
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        final String TAG = "AsyncTaskParseJson.java";
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
            // Getting JSON from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                // Getting JSON Array
                user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_DATA);
                // loop through all users
                for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Storing JSON item in a Variable
                    String idt = c.getString(TAG_IDT);
                    String idl = c.getString(TAG_IDL);
                    String nama = c.getString(TAG_NAMA);
                    String alamat = c.getString(TAG_ALAMAT);
                    String image = c.getString(TAG_IMAGE);

                    // code for get image url and make byte
                    logoImage = getLogoImage(IMAGEURL+image);

                    databaseHelper.saveCategoryRecord(idt, idl, nama, alamat, image, logoImage);

                    // Set JSON Data in TextView
                //  uid.setText(idt);
                    //name1.setText(name);
                    // email1.setText(email);
                    // show the values in our logcat
                    Log.e(TAG, "nama >>>> " + idt + "  alamat>>>>> " + nama);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    // try get url and make byte
    private byte[] getLogoImage(String geturl) {
        try {
            URL imageUrl = new URL(geturl);
            URLConnection ucon = imageUrl.openConnection();

            InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(500);
            int current = 0;

            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            return baf.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

and this is mydatabase handler

```
public class DatabaseHandler {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "bantul";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "tb_alldata";
    public static final String TAG_IDT = "idt";
    public static final String TAG_IDL = "idl";
    public static final String TAG_NAMA = "nama";
    public static final String TAG_ALAMAT = "alamat";
    public static final String TAG_IMAGE = "image";
    public static final String TAG_FILE_IMAGE = "file_image";

    Category openHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase database;

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context){
        openHelper = new Category(context);
        database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    public void saveCategoryRecord(String idt, String idl, String nama, String alamat, String image, byte[] logoImage) {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(TAG_IDT, idt);
        contentValues.put(TAG_IDL, idl);
        contentValues.put(TAG_NAMA, nama);
        contentValues.put(TAG_ALAMAT, alamat);
        contentValues.put(TAG_IMAGE, image);
        contentValues.put(TAG_FILE_IMAGE, logoImage);

        database.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
        }
    public Cursor getTimeRecordList() {
        return database.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME, null);
        }

    private class Category extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public Category(Context context) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "( "
                    + TAG_IDT + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                    + TAG_IDL + " INTEGER, "+ TAG_NAMA + " TEXT, "+ TAG_ALAMAT + " TEXT, "+ TAG_IMAGE + " TEXT, "
                    + TAG_FILE_IMAGE + " BLOB, )" );
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS"+ TABLE_NAME);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why there isn't TAG_IMAGE in create table ?

Comment: @issanthink sorry i mistyped :(, i have edit

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly an answer to your question: while it is possible to do this, it is probably a bad idea.

SQLite efficiency depends on the concept of a "page".  The more you can keep references to a single page, the better your DB will perform.

When you start using BLOBs, there is the possibility that, not only will a single row not be entirely on a single page, but a single BLOB may not be on a single page.  That will dramatically slow access times.

You can set the page size, but that takes lots of memory.

If you *must* keep the images in a database, I suggest that you keep them in a *separate* databases.  Set the page size default in the primary database and appropriate for your BLOB size in the other.  Store the PK of the BLOB in the primary db.

Better yet, just save the images on the file system, with random names, and store the names in the primary DB.  ContentProviders even support the openFile method, to make this really easy.

Your code actually looks about right.  Perhaps it is something as simple as TAG_FILE_GAMAR != TAG_FILE_IMAGE?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested @G. Blake Meike instead of BLOB, use a String to store your image.

Here how you can encode you bytes :

`String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArrayImage, Base64.DEFAULT);`